# How to add column from another csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have several csv files in one folder. it is about 60th files. So, i want to make a new csv file and using only two columns from each file, like below :

This is an example :

```
1.csv                2.csv              3.csv            4.csv and so on...

a   b   c   d        a   b   c   d      a   b   c   d    a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4        8   3   5   7      2   9   4   6    3   6   8   3
4   2   8   3        6   3   6   7      9   3   4   5    3   6   6   8
3   9   4   8        9   3   4   2      4   7   4   4    1   8   3   5
```

I want to add a only two column from each csv file...

I have tried my script below :

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import csv

path = "C:/Users/SYIFAAZRA/Documents/belajar_wradlib/Skew-T/"
os.chdir(path)

file = glob.glob("*.csv")

x=0
for files in file:
    x=x+1

    df = pd.read_csv(files, delimiter=',', skiprows=7, usecols=[11, 22])
    df1 = df.merge(df, how='right')
    df2 = pd.concat([df1])

print (df2)
```

I want to make a new column such as below :

```
a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b
1   2   8   3   2   9   3   6
4   2   6   3   9   3   3   6
3   9   9   3   4   7   1   8
```

can some one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because already filtered columns by parameter `usecols` create list of DataFrames in loop:

```
path = "C:/Users/SYIFAAZRA/Documents/belajar_wradlib/Skew-T/"
os.chdir(path)

filenames = glob.glob("*.csv")

dfs = []
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',', skiprows=7, usecols=[11, 22])
    dfs.append(df)
```

Or in list comprehension:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',', skiprows=7, usecols=[11, 22]) for f in filenames]
```

And join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df2)
```

Better solution with avoid duplicated columns names is create `MultiIndex` with `keys` parameter and then flatten it by `f-string`s:

```
df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=np.arange(len(dfs)))
df2.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df2.columns]
print (df2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael